# how to show combobox in datagrid in vb.net

Tags: view, combobox, grid, show

I have this query below and I want to show items that sold depending on sales_id without repeat the old ids. And another question how to make a combo box data grid view:

```
Private Sub filldatagrid()
        Dim myTableName As String
        myTableName = txtid.Text
        winclass.filldatagrid(DataGridView1, "select inventory.inv_name,sales_data.sales_id,sales_data.quantity,sales_data.sum_total from sales_data,inventory where sales_data.inv_id=inventory.inv_id ")

    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = True
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
End Sub
```